# Firefox renders blank PDFs in 20-200% zoom range after waking up from sleep

Tags: firefox, suspend, pdf, gpu-driver

After booting into Ubuntu, Firefox successfully renders PDF files at all levels of zoom (10-400% zoom).

However, when I suspend my PC (the "Sleep" feature in Ubuntu) and wake up the PC from sleep, Firefox renders just blank pages of that PDF at zoom levels >10% and <200%. When I zoom-out to 10% or zoom-in to >=200%, the PDF's text and *most* of the images in the PDF gets rendered.

Despite no visible text or images, I can select the text and contents of the PDF with mouse (see the attached image) and copy the selected text just fine.

This happens with multiple PDFs, so it doesn't seem specific to a particular PDF file. Not even force-reloading the tab with the PDF helps (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>). Opening the same PDF in a new tab is also of no help. This bug happens even with newly opened PDFs in new tabs. What helps is quitting Firefox and opening it again.

Sometimes, it seems like parts of the GPU's framebuffer (i.e. a window of a different app from which I just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>bed to Firefox) get displayed in the area where the PDF should be rendered.

It seems like GPU's VRAM is not getting saved to RAM when the PC gets to sleep. However, this does not explain why even newly opened PDFs in new tabs are blank at the 10-200% zoom level.

I should add that I use a Nvidia GPU with the proprietary driver.

[image: Contents can be highlighted despite not being visibly rendered.]

Comment: sounds like a firefox bug, you can report it on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox

Comment: Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox?

Comment: Nearly same problem here. In my case, reloading the tab usually renders the document again. Ubuntu 23.10, Firefox snap 123.0